# What shear strengthening schemes are available for an I beam?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, steel

I would like to double the shear capacity of an I beam by welding some steel plates. What strengthening schemes are available? How would you define the shear area for the strengthening scheme proposed?

Comment: Duplicate of : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/how-to-strengthen-an-i-beam?rq=1

Comment: @SolarMike, my question here is for shear strengthening, the other question is moment strengthening. These are two different question.

Comment: Apply what you have been given then - and check out the applicable theory

Answer (score -2):

The web have almost all the resistance to shear. I recommend to review the basic texts of mechanics of materials, such as that of James M Gere.

Comment: Please put any required information in your answer. A recommendation to a book does not help very much. The answer should mainly stand on its own.